# Can't use LG IPS224V-PN on Fedora 17 as second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, fedora-17, lg-monitor

I tried to connect my monitor via HDMI and VGA.  The screen turn on with the Fedora logo, but it isn't detected in the "Display and Monitor" system settings.

I am currently updating the system with yum to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out it would work with VGA only after yum update and a reboot. The max resolution wasn't available in the ui. 
So I typed xrandr in the console to be sure, and I had the correct settings available, I typed

```
  xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1920x1080
```

It updated the monitor display and the UI info, then I was able to setup my dual monitor config correctly in the manager.